# All records not showing when using a WHERE statement with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation, where-clause

I have a list of plant, which can be filtered with a CONCAT, originally it was just text, but I have converted it to ID's instead. It was showing all records and could be filtered before I converted to ID's.

This involves 4 tables. (with example data) "" are not used in the fields, they are just to show you that it is a word.

**plant**

```
idplant example 1
plantname example "001 Forklift"
idplanttype1 example 1
idlocation1 example 1
iddepartment1 example 1
```

**planttypes**

```
idplanttype example 1
planttype example "Forklift Truck"
```

**locations**

```
idlocation example 1
location example "Preston"
```

**departments**

```
iddepartment example 1
department example "Waste Disposal"
```

Without the WHERE statement, it shows all records, including nulls. (but the filter doesn't work)

But With the WHERE statement, it is only showing complete records (all of which have no Null fields and the filter works) records with nulls do not show

The issue seems to be the CONCAT. (i've cleaned up the parentheses, but had to add a 1 to make the id's different)

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];}

$sql = "
SELECT idplant, plantname, planttype, location, department
FROM plant

LEFT JOIN planttypes ON idplanttype1 = idplanttype
LEFT JOIN locations ON idlocation1 = idlocation
LEFT JOIN departments ON iddepartment1 = iddepartment

WHERE CONCAT(plantname, planttype, location, department) LIKE 
'%".$valueToSearch."%' 

ORDER BY plantname";
```

**SOLUTION**
The above code works, it was just missing.

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS
```

I'm new to Joins, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Using Linux Server - Apache Version 2.4.46

Thanks in advance!

Comment: plz, elaborate on what kind of records you want? from your question, it's not clear.

Comment: please provide examples of your data in each table

Comment: You should start with removing all those useless parentheses around your join conditions that would make reading the query a lot easier. And please add a tag for the DBMS product you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably blanks.

```
WHERE CONCAT(plantname, planttype, location, department) 
 LIKE '%001 Forklift Forklift Truck Preston Waste Disposal%'
```

won't find anything for example, as the concated strings result in `'001 ForkliftForklift TruckPrestonWaste Disposal'`, not `'001 Forklift Forklift Truck Preston Waste Disposal'`.

You want blanks between the substrings, which is easiest to achieve with `CONCAT_WS`:

```
SELECT p.idplant, p.plantname, pt.planttype, l.location, d.department
FROM plant p
INNER JOIN planttypes pt ON pt.idplanttype = p.idplanttype1
INNER JOIN locations l ON l.idlocation = p.idlocation1
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.iddepartment = p.iddepartment1
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', p.plantname, pt.planttype, l.location, d.department) 
        LIKE '%001 Forklift Forklift Truck Preston Waste Disposal%'
```

Comment: That's great thanks, had to fiddle with it a bit, but you were right about the _WS